# Solving return function without list comprhensions or loops?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a function called "Positive" that is supposed to return the sum of all the even numbers from `n - 0` given a number `n`. I also have to use recursion without using list comprehension or loops. Can anyone help me?

This function call:

```
Positive (8)
```

should output:

```
20 # which is 8 + 6 + 4 + 2
```

Comment: is that your homework? what have you tried so far?

Comment: You question is unclear. You need to return a list? you need to return a sum? you need to return only the some of the even numbers?

Comment: yes sorry! i need to return the sum of the even numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return the sum of the even number:

```
def Positive(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x + Positive(x - 1)
    return Positive(x - 1)
```

This

```
print(Positive(8))
```

Will generate the output:

```
20   # Which is 8 + 6 + 4 + 2
```